# Why doesn't java.lang.ref.Reference<T> implement Supplier<T>?

Tags: java, reference, garbage-collection, functional-interface

I'm looking at the class `java.lang.ref.Reference` (and it's sub-classes) and I'm wondering why it doesn't implement Java 8's `Supplier<T>` interface.

Seems like this should be a no-brainer. Supplier's `get()` method is satisfied by `Reference`. The only reason I'm hesitating to implement an extension of `SoftReference<T>` myself that also implements `Supplier<T>` is because I know that `References` are special-cased by the garbage collector.

Are there any problems you can forsee with making a class like this

```
public class SoftReferenceSupplier<T> extends SoftReference<T> implements Supplier<T>
{
    public SoftReferenceSupplier(T referent)
    {
        super(referent);
    }

    public SoftReferenceSupplier<T referent, ReferenceQueue<? super T> queue)
    {
        super(referent,queue);
    }
}
```

I don't want to in some way defeat the purpose of SoftReferences because of some garbage collection caveats interferring with how Supplier's are handled.

BTW, I am aware the `SoftReferences` will return `null` upon a full garbage collection. I have a need `SoftReferences` in my program and I'd like to have it implement this function interface in order to increase the flexibility.

Comment: Because this would break backward compability. Reference is java 2, Supplier is java 8. If Reference implemented Supplier, java 2 would require java 8. Also because it would not really make sense (Reference is a wrapper, not a supplier of values).

Comment: why would it increase flexibility?

Comment: Can't you just pass `ref::get` to any method that wants a Supplier?

Comment: @sturcotte06 why would it break backward compatibility? Java2 users wouldn't be affected, since the change would be in Java 8 (or 9) only. String didn't implement CharSequence in Java 2, and it does now, for a counter-example.

Comment: And all clients migrating from java < 8 to java 8, extending `Reference<T>` would be broken. Also, String is a final class, Sun (or Oracle) can do whatever the heck they want with it, as long as changes are only additive.

Comment: Why would they be broken? Their class would just automatically also implement Supplier, since Reference would already implement it. If you want a non-final counter-example, AbstractList now implements Iterable, and didn't back then. Vector now implements RandomAccess and Iterable, and didn't back then. And there are plenty of other examples.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi I'm working on a sort of "facade" class. It's like Optional, except that internally, it can store the object in some alternative form that is perhaps easier on the memory. In one extended implementation, I'd like to internally store a memory-hungry object in a soft reference and use a sort of "key" object as an anchor. When the soft-reference expires, a call to "get" would trigger a refresh of the Soft Reference. My implementation makes a lot more sense if you can think of the internally stored value as a Supplier. So I want the Reference to be a Supplier.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi Mind you, this is experimental. I have an existing library I'm working on that I want to retrofit with this capability. Hoping to bemore frugal with memory usage.

Comment: @VGR Why didn't I think of that? That would indeed do what I want it to. Still, I think that if it doesn't break existing code (I have no idea if it would or not), the folks at Oracle should just go ahead and have Reference implement Supplier. It otherwise satisfies the requirements of the Supplier interface.

Answer (score 1):

`Reference` is a lot older than `Supplier`. As far as I can tell, changing `Reference<T>` to implement `Supplier<T>` would not have broken any existing code, however in my view it wouldn't make a lot of sense. When all the new functional interfaces were introduced into the language, it would have been possible to have gone through every existing class and make each one implement every new functional interface that happened to have a matching method, but I can't see the value of this.

In many cases, there is no point in a class actually implementing a functional interface at all, because if you need to regard an object as an instance of a functional interface, you can just use a method reference.

```
Reference<Object> reference = new WeakReference<>(someObject);
Supplier<Object> supplier = reference::get;
```

This solution does *not* depend on the fact that the two methods happen to both be called `get`, so in my view it is preferable to making `Reference` implement `Supplier`.

Answer (score 0):

I did some Googling, but didn't find anything related to why Java's [Reference class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html) doesn't implement the [Supplier interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html). But the Javadoc of `Supplier` leaves some clues. I think that the answer lies in how the `Supplier` was introduced to Java - namely as a functional programming interface for use in Lambda expressions. The meanings of the two `get()` methods just mean logically different things. The `get()` method of an instance of the Reference class returns the referent; the `get()` method of `Supplier` instance returns the result of a lambda expression. It's hard to imagine a semantic overlap between the two, unless I was creating a lambda expression involving JVM soft, weak, and/or phantom references.